# How to change examdesign class language?

Tags: spanish, examdesign

I'm trying to change the whole exam language to spanish, I've tried with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` but it doesn't work for sections neither student's data. My code is written below:

```
\documentclass[opt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\OneKey
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\class{Alguna materia}
\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}[title={Opción múltiple}]
    \begin{question}
    Elegir la respuesta correcta:\\
    \choice{Incorrecta}
    \choice[!]{Correcta}
    \choice{Incorrecta}
    \end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Shouldn't bable be able to handle everything?  Or do you also want to change the macro name?

Answer (score 1):

`examdesign` doesn't support `bable`, at least not for the still English words (and btw. `bable` has no `\sectionname`). They are fixed in the code. But you can set/redefine things to translate these words. It's in the manual, but not easy to find (I searched the source).

In the code below I marked the translation with `%   ^^^` below. Check them!

```
\documentclass[opt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\OneKey
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% manual page 3
\SectionPrefix{Sección \arabic{sectionindex}. \space}
%              ^^^^^^^ check translation!

% manual page 3
\examname{Examen}
%         ^^^^^^

% manual page 10
\begin{examtop}
\@@line{\parbox{3in}{\classdata \\
        \examtype, Formar:~\fbox{\textsf{\Alph{version}}}}
%                  ^^^^^^
        \hfill
        \parbox{3in}{\normalsize \namedata}}
        \bigskip
\end{examtop}

% manual page 10
\def\namedata{Nombre: \hrulefill \\[\namedata@vspace]
%             ^^^^^^
              Número de Estudiante: \hrulefill \\[\namedata@vspace]
%             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              TA: \hrulefill \\[\namedata@vspace]
%             ^^ not translated
              Fecha: \hrulefill}
%             ^^^^^
\makeatother

\class{Alguna materia}
\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}[title={Opción múltiple}]
    \begin{question}
    Elegir la respuesta correcta:\\
    \choice{Incorrecta}
    \choice[!]{Correcta}
    \choice{Incorrecta}
    \end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```